# Yii2 show activation pending message on login

Tags: php, authentication, yii2, yii2-user

I am using `yii2` advanced for my application.

When I login to my application, if user is not activated ( his account status is 0 in user table ), I need show warning message "Account activation Pending".

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i can't able to find where from this message " username/password  incorrect " come . if found it i can write custome changes here

Comment: At basic template this message (Incorrect username or password.)  is at loginForm.php model,you may write custom validators http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html

Comment: /common/models/LoginForm.php .public function validatePassword($attribute, $params){}